# Detecting when nested RecyclerView item is attached/detached from user view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a RecyclerView with a list of RecyclerViews inside of it. Basically, I have a list of rooms, and each room can have a list of devices inside of it. I have implemented the code and the app is able to show all the items. However, when I scroll through the items, only the rooms trigger the `onViewAttachedToWindow` & `onViewDetachedFromWindow` functions when a room is scrolled in/out of the user's view. However, when the devices inside of each room are scrolled in/out of the user's view, they do not trigger these functions. Why does the device nested RecyclerView not trigger the `onViewAttachedToWindow` & `onViewDetachedFromWindow` functions when the device is scrolled in/out of the user's view, and how can I fix it?

Here are the relevant pieces of code implemented in Kotlin.

1. MainFragment

```kotlin
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
    recyclerView = binding.recyclerView;
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context);
    val dataset = ...
    val adapter = RoomRecyclerViewAdapter(
        requireContext(),
        dataset
    )
    recyclerView.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.roomsList.observe(requireActivity()) {
        dataset.clear()
        dataset.addAll(it)
        recyclerView.post { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }
    }
}
```

2. RoomRecyclerViewAdapter

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    deviceRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    // devices that are children of this room
    val devicesDataset = ...
    val devicesAdapter = DeviceRecyclerViewAdapter(
            context,
            devicesDataset,
    )
    deviceRecyclerView.adapter = devicesAdapter
}

override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    Timber.i("room onViewAttachedToWindow")
}

override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    Timber.i("room onViewDetachedFromWindow")
}
```

3. DeviceRecyclerViewAdapter

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    ...
}

override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewAttachedToWindow(holder)
    Timber.i("device onViewAttachedToWindow")
}

override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: ViewHolder) {
    super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    Timber.i("device onViewDetachedFromWindow")
}
```